# SQL Server get attack information

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I use `SQL Server` on my server and have attack from a local network computers. 
I read sql server error log by following query :

```
DECLARE @LogFromDate VARCHAR(50),
@LogToDate VARCHAR(50)

SET @LogFromDate = CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DateTime)
SET @LogToDate = GETDATE()

DECLARE @T TABLE (LogDate DATETIME, ProcessInfo NVARCHAR(50), text NVARCHAR(MAX))


INSERT into @T
exec sys.xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Login failed for user ', NULL, @LogFromDate, @LogToDate

SELECT *
FROM @T
```

and active Security Audit for `FAILED_LOGIN_GROUP` on the sql server and get result of this audit by following query :

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.fn_get_audit_file('e:\audit\security\ser*',DEFAULT,DEFAULT)
```

I get only IP Address and username of failed connection from above queries.

but I can't find application or service that want to connect to my server. How can determine Application Name/Service Name on this IP computer(this computer have an application server and work correctly and I can't filter this ip in windows firewall).

thanks in advance.